# RoR and json: Update a count on button click

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to get a count to update on my view on a button click on my page without a page refresh

application.js

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', '.follow-btn-show', function(e){
  let data = e.detail[0];
  let $el = $(this);
  let method = this.dataset.method;
  if (method === 'post') {
    $el.text('Unfollow');
    this.dataset.method = 'delete';
  } else if (method === 'delete') {
    $el.text('Follow');
    this.dataset.method = 'post';
  }
});
```

This works perfect for the button change but how do I get my count to update on click to a different div? I tried attaching this:

`$(this).text(`${data.count}`);`

but it updates on the button where I don't want it and I have not assigned the div attribute to my script there. I need to assign the attribute and have it update but I don't know how.

My count in the view

```
<div class="loop"><b><%= @user.followers.count %></b></div> Followers
```

Controller

```
def create
    current_user.follow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json do
        render json: { count: @user.followers.count },
               status: :created  
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_user.unfollow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json do
        render json: { count: @user.followers.count }, 
               status: :ok
      end
    end
  end
```

Any suggestions?

ty

Comment: Start with some basic jquery tutorials on [DOM traversal](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/jquery/jquery-traversing-dom-elements) and [manipulating elements](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/). This is not a code writing service and you need to make a minimal effort to research and solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't know where to put the code rather than the code itself because I need to integrate with the js you provided. Maybe easy for you, not easy for noobs. I am trying, I just don't have it right yet. Thanks for the links.

Comment: Its not really that difficult but you're not really specifying what the connection (if there is any at all) is between the button and where you are displaying the count. You need to start by figuring out how to connect the two and the pieces will fall into place. You know teach a man to fish and all that. I'm really doing you a disservice if you keep getting spoon-fed code that you don't understand how to modify.

Comment: I understand the code you have given and taken a lot from it (much appreciated). The problem is I don't know where in the script to attach my own code. I have tried attaching code here and there but either it renders on the button or nothing works. It's very frustrating. In fairness you know I have asked about the count in the last question. It's not new. I'm not trying to exploit, i'm genuinely stuck. I'll get it myself eventually but a nudge would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is I just reload the div with the id after click...

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', '.follow-btn', function(e) {
  let data = e.detail[0];
  let method = this.dataset.method === 'post' ? 'delete' : 'post';
  let txt = {
    post: 'Follow',
    delete: 'Unfollow'
  }[method];
  //loop
  $(`.follow-btn[href="${this.getAttribute('href')}"]`).each(function() {
    this.dataset.method = method;
    $(this).text(`${txt}`);
  });
   $("#following_count").load(" #following_count > *")
});
```

In my view

```
<div id="following_count" class="inline">...<%= current_user.following.count %>...</div>
```

Not sure how efficient or fail-safe this is but it works.